# String search in Access Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access

I am new to this site.  I have a question about data structures.  Here's the project:
I have a MS Access Database, with approx 50 tables.  Each table has an index field (sequential auto number) and 10-12 Memo type fields.  These fields can contain small or large amounts of text.  In all, the DB contains between 20,000 - 40,000 individual strings (Memo field entries).

I am looking for a way to search for a string in all of these tables (using C# / ASP.NET). I do not have a lot of exposure to either Access, C# or ASP..but..I am thinking that there may be a data structure that might be more suitable (than any other) that might work.  I am conscious that reading that amount of data into any data structure would be a memory hog, which is why I am asking the question. So the question relates specifically to suitable data structures (arrays, linked lists, etc) that might be the most appropriate.  I will try to figure the rest out later..

Thanks..

Comment: First try obtaining the data from the table into a 'DataTable'( using the Disconnected Architecture )/use 'DataSet'( in case of more than one table ), this would put a less overhead on the DB, 'coz you wanna execute a search operation. Then iterate through rows of the obtained DataTable/DataSet to match you string.

Comment: Go through this link to connect access DB to C# code via ADO.net - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mimrantaj/connect-to-access-database-in-C-Sharp-and-ado-net/ , then fire `select` query with required `where` , `LIKE` clause, to fetch data.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is to connect to your database first in order to get the data necessary at first hand. You can look it up there to help yourself : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655884(v=vs.90).aspx

Then, you'll then be able to select the needed data, for instance the strings,  with your database with SqlDataSource. In order to get more information is this situation, look there : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1kdt8w2(v=vs.90).aspx

Finally, if you were to connect to your database and put the data in a data structure like a list or a an arraylist. Don't put it in a set because you cannot repeat data in a set, if you have more than once the same string, you'll end up with false(missing) data.
Since this is quite important to know, I would strongly refer you to go to msdn and look up this : An Extensive Examination of Data Structures Using C# 2.0. It will provide you with better knowledge of data structure so you'll know next time what you need

Hope it helps you !

Comment: Good answer Kevin, although I'm wondering whether it met the OP's need for others to provide a code dump to do this assignment!

Comment: It might sound insignificant, but I am unfamiliair with the term OP? Did you mean OOP as object oriented programming?

Comment: OP means original poster   ;-)

Comment: If the answer that @KevinAvignon provided was the good answer for you, check it as the good answer in the situation you were in !! :-)